# Can someone imitate and create a fake erc20 contract? If so, how can we identify a contract?

Tags: go-ethereum, tokens, erc-20, etherscan

If a project A deployed a erc20 token contract **Mytoken**, can a scammer create another **Mytoken** with some internal data modified (e.g., founder address)?

Can etherscan identify such fake contracts?

Or the only solution it to put the address of the real **Mytoken** on project's website? But there could be fake website...

Answer (score 3):

The main identifier of any contract is not the metadata associated with the contract, but rather the contract **address**. Etherscan and other clients will use the address as the identifier for the token. Anybody can make an exact copy of paste of any contract, but nobody can do so with the contract being deployed to the same address.

In the case of Etherscan choosing which token is the *real* token, they accept a form from the entity creating the token that states the associated website, GitHub, etc. that go along with that token. The reason the *real* token comes up first in Etherscan searches is because of sheer traffic and interest in that specific token (read: address)